# Adding a domain after a name field on a registration form

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I am trying to add a domain after a name field and not having success.   name field @domain.com

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$js = "
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Define the variables
    var regForm     = $('#member-registration');
    var name        = regForm.find('#jform_name'); @domain.com<<<
    var password    = regForm.find('#jform_password1');
    var password2   = regForm.find('#jform_password2');
    var email       = regForm.find('#jform_email1');
    var email2      = regForm.find('#jform_email2');
    regForm.find('.spacer').parents('.control-group').hide();
    regForm.find('.star').hide();
    email.parents('.control-group').hide();
    password2.parents('.control-group').hide();
    email2.parents('.control-group').hide();  
    password.on('keyup', function() {
        password2.val( this.value );
    });
    name.on('keyup', function() {
        email.val( this.value );
    });
    email.on('keyup', function() {
        email2.val( this.value );
    });
    });    
";    
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Adding the domain would then allow the registration to pass the email stage and generate a email. I don't want to require a user to register with a email since I myself am a email provider.

```
 name.on('keyup', function() {
        email.val( this.value );
    });
```

thanks for any advice.. been at it for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for your question

Try below code to get exact domain

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var domain = window.location.hostname;
  if(domain.indexOf('www.') >= 0)
  {
    domain = domain.replace('www.', '');
  }       
  domain = "@"+domain;

  $("#name").on('keyup', function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().indexOf(domain) >= 0)
    {
      inputVal = inputVal.split(domain);
      inputVal = inputVal[0];
    }
    $(this).val(inputVal+domain)
    setCaretToPos(document.getElementById("name"), inputVal.length);
  });
  $( "#name" ).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key >= 48 && key <= 57 || key == 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
      input.focus();
      input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
    else if (input.createTextRange) {
      var range = input.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
      range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
      range.select();
    }
  }

  function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
    setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name -</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="name" />
```

Comment: Hello, how do I incorporate that into the var name field?    name.on('keyup', function() {
        email.val( this.value + Domain? );
    });

Comment: Hi please check updated snippet and let me know.

Comment: Hi, the name field is already set within the form as var name        = regForm.find('#jform_name');  I am having a hard time running your script with the original script i posted. That original script hides fields. Is there a way you can post your script already merged with my original script? also the www. i can replace with my domain correct? thanks i am super new when it comes to js

Comment: Another way i found that works is by setting a default email value.  email.val('Public@domain.com'); but, this would only allow one registration because you can't sign up with the same email twice.. so it does not work unless i can randomize it.